# What is the best way to convert an array to a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array: `a = ["a", "b", "c"]` and I want convert to a hash `h = {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}`
where the key is the position of the array. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify the language please?

Comment: Do you want to do this on paper or you intend to use some specific programming language ?

Comment: Looks like Ruby to me

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. The language is ruby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way in Ruby would be:

```
h = Hash[a.map.with_index { |s, i| [ i + 1, s ] }]
```

If you `a.map` without a block, you get an Enumerator object, then you can get the indexes by iterating over that Enumerator with `with_index`. Then it is just a simple matter of adjusting the starting index and arranging things in the right order for `Hash[]`.

You could also do it this way (which is pretty much a transliteration of House's Java answer):

```
h = { }
a.each_with_index { |s, i| h[i + 1] = s }
```

Which way you do it is mostly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
Hash[(1..a.length).zip(a)]
```

`1..a.length` gives you `[1,2,3]` (after an implicit conversion)

[zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip)(a) gives you `[1,"a",2,"b",3,"c"]`

Comment: if you're code golfing then you can use size instead of length, but I think length reads better here.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array, in Java it would be the following.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    map.put(Integer.valueOf(i), array[i]);
}
```

Comment: `map.put(i+1, array[i]);` OP wants the key to start from 1 and you can use auto-boxing.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in Python:

```
>>> dict((k, v) for k, v in enumerate(["a", "b", "c"]))
{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot. The language is ruby

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
Hash[a.map.with_index(1){|i,ind| [ind,i] }]
# >> {1=>"a", 2=>"b", 3=>"c"}
```